# How to dynamically load images from a URL into ImageView from a ViewModel in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, picasso, android-viewmodel

I am writing an app to display NHL scores, and would like for each team in the RecyclerView to have their logo next to it.  There is a URL that I can request with a team's ID that will return a hi-res image of the team's logo.  I am trying to make it so that I can load the images in my viewModel and set them in the view, as I'm doing for things like the team name, current score, etc.

I have tried using Picasso for this, but it requires a context, which the viewModel doesn't have, and the viewModel cannot directly access the imageView to be able to change it.  So how can I load the images and expose them either with data binding or something else, to allow the view to display them?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: GameListViewModel
    private var errorSnackbar: Snackbar? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.gameList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GameListViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.errorMessage.observe(this, Observer { errorMessage ->
            if (errorMessage != null)
                showError(errorMessage)
            else
                hideError()
        })
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    private fun showError(@StringRes errorMessage:Int) {
        errorSnackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.root, errorMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        errorSnackbar?.setAction(R.string.retry, viewModel.errorClickListener)
        errorSnackbar?.show()
    }

    private fun hideError() {
        errorSnackbar?.dismiss()
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class GameViewModel:BaseViewModel() {
    private val awayTeamName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val homeTeamName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val awayTeamScore = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val homeTeamScore = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val timeRemaining = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun bind(response: Game) {
        awayTeamName.value = response.gameData.teams.away.name
        homeTeamName.value = response.gameData.teams.home.name
        awayTeamScore.value = response.liveData.linescore.teams["away"]?.goals.toString()
        homeTeamScore.value = response.liveData.linescore.teams["home"]?.goals.toString()

        if (response.gameData.status.detailedState == "Scheduled") {
            val parser = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
            parser.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
            timeRemaining.value = formatter.format(parser.parse(response.gameData.datetime.dateTime))
        } else {
            timeRemaining.value = response.liveData.linescore.currentPeriodTimeRemaining + " " + response.liveData.linescore.currentPeriodOrdinal
        }
    }

    fun getAwayTeamName(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return awayTeamName
    }

    fun getHomeTeamName(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return homeTeamName
    }

    fun getAwayTeamScore(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return awayTeamScore
    }

    fun getHomeTeamScore(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return homeTeamScore
    }

    fun getTimeRemaining(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return timeRemaining
    }
}
```

and XML for the recyclerView row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.nhlstats.ui.game.GameViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/awayTeam"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/awayTeamLogo"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/awayTeamName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@{viewModel.awayTeamName}"
                tools:text="CHI Blackhawks"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/awayScore"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@{viewModel.awayTeamScore}"
                tools:text="0"/>
            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/gameTime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@{viewModel.timeRemaining}"
                tools:text="14:26 3rd"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeTeam"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/homeTeamLogo"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/homeTeamName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@{viewModel.homeTeamName}"
                tools:text="CAR Hurricanes"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/homeScore"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="@{viewModel.homeTeamScore}"
                tools:text="4"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a LiveData variable for the url in ViewModel and observe it in the itemView

Comment: hey @cpgreen2 making network requests in VewModel is not good practice, create repository class to do the work follow [this guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

Comment: @Duy Khan Nguyen How would observing the URL get the image to show up in the ImageView?

Comment: You can check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using data binding you should create a custom binding adapter like below:

```
  @BindingAdapter("app:imageUri")
    fun loadImageWithUri(imageView: ImageView, imageUri: String){
      Glide.with(imageView.context).load(Uri.parse(imageUri)).into(imageView)
  }
```

And change you imageview like this:

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
  android:layout_height="36dp"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  app:imageUri="@{viewmodel.teamLogoUri}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Android Architecture Components View Model,

It's not a good practice to pass your Activity Context to the Activity's ViewModel as its a memory leak. I don't support to to that.

You can create image url observer in viewmodel and observe it in your View class (Activity or fragment), Like this (as *Duy Khanh Nguyen* answered):-

```
    viewModel.url.observe(this, Observer { 
     it?.let { url ->
        //So image into itemView using Picasso
     }
   })
```

But if you want to go with otherwise you can simply use an **Application context** which is provided by the `AndroidViewModel`, you should extend `AndroidViewModel` which is simply a `ViewModel` that includes an `Application` reference. I your case do it into your `BaseViewModel`. Example:-

```
class BaseViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

val context = getApplication<Application>().applicationContext

//... ViewModel methods 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guest you'll create `GameViewModel` for each itemView, so when binding the view holder:

Your `GameViewModel` class

```
val awayLogoUrl = MutableLiveData<String>()
val homeLogoUrl = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun bind(response: Game) {
    awayLogoUrl.value = response... //set away logo url here
    homeLogoUrl.value = response... //set home logo url here
}
```

Your `ViewHolder` class

```
viewModel.awayLogoUrl.observe(this, Observer { 
    it?.let { url ->
        //Show image into itemView using Picasso or Glide
        Glide.with(itemView.context).load(url).into(binding.awayTeamLogo)
    }
})

viewModel.homeLogoUrl.observe(this, Observer { 
    it?.let { url ->
        //Show image into itemView using Picasso or Glide
        Glide.with(itemView.context).load(url).into(binding.homeTeamLogo)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, that's helpful.  That would work well if I had a single imageView, but as I mentioned I'm trying to do this for a RecyclerView.  Each row item has two images (both different), and there are an indefinite amount of rows.  How could I set the different images for each row using something like this?

Comment: Can you add the Adapter class to your post. It's easier to show you where the codes show be added.